# GNUPLOT : A better way of piping data into gnuplot script

Tags: shell, gnuplot

I have a gnuplot script like this (simplified)

```
reset session

set terminal pngcairo enhanced font "Times,25" size 800,400

filename = ifilename

stats filename nooutput

N = STATS_columns
M = STATS_records

set angles degrees
set size square 1.25,1

set output ofilename

# does some stuff
...
...
...

set parametric  

plot \ 
    for [i=2:N] filename u (posX($0, column(i))):(posY($0, column(i))) w p ps 1.2 pt 7 lc rgb lcolor(i-2)
```

What I want to do is define `ifilename` (input file) and `ofilename` (output file) via a shell script.

So I thought the `-e` command might just be the one for the job.

So for the gnuploat part of the script I wroth this

```
gnuplot -e "ifilename='data/points_data1.dat'; ofilename='plot1'" chart.gp
```

but it threw the error

```
"chart.gp" line 8: undefined variable: ifilename
```

which refers to this line

```
filename = ifilename
```

I thought maybe that's because it's having some trouble parsing two `=` signs so I removed that line and rewrote my shell script like this

```
gnuplot -e "filename='data/points_data1.dat'; ofilename='plot1'" chart.gp
```

but this time it threw the following error

```
"chart.gp" line 8: undefined variable: filename
```

---

What actually worked was this

```
echo "data/points_data$i.dat" | gnuplot chart.gp
```

where I replaced the line `filename = ifilename`  with

```
FILE = system("read filename; echo $filename")
```

and every instance of `filename` with `FILE` in `.gp` script.

But I'm not sure how to use that syntax to also define the output file.

---

So I was wondering, is there a better way of piping shell input into gnuplot script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FILE = system("read filename; echo $filename")
```

is actually fine.

If you want to pipe the output to some file you can just omit `set output "something.png"`

and instead you could just send the `.png` output directly to `stdout` by running a script like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

reset session

set terminal pngcairo enhanced font "Times,25" size 800,400
...
```

then you can pipe that output to a `.png` file like this

```
./chart.gp > mypng.png
```

So the final command would look something like this

```
echo "data/points_data$i.dat" | gnuplot chart.gp > plot$i.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original command almost worked.  The invocation

```
gnuplot -e "ifilename='data/points_data1.dat'; ofilename='plot1'" chart.gp
```

correctly defined the input and output file names.  But then you clobbered them inside the chart.gp script by issuing the command

```
  reset session
```

which clears all variable definitions including the ones you specifically wanted. Remove that line from the script and you should be fine.   If the intent of the "reset session" command was to make sure that no system-wide or private initialization file is used, then replace it with a "-d" on the command line:

```
  gnuplot -d -e "ifilename='data/points_data1.dat'; ofilename='plot1'" chart.gp
```